# UnknownHostException: us-east-api.getstream.io

Tags: getstream-io

I get frequently UnknownHostException. How do I solve this? I have added the IP in the machine's host file. (/etc/hosts).

```
52.202.186.221  us-east-api.getstream.io
54.165.144.222  us-east-api.getstream.io
52.72.192.142   us-east-api.getstream.io
```

After adding the frequency was reduced but still get the exception.

**Exeception :**

```
2017-04-27 08:07:55,502 ERROR [notes-activity-service] de.notes.activity.rest.ActivityBaseResource  - Exception Occurred : Internal server error
java.net.UnknownHostException: us-east-api.getstream.io: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
2017-04-27 08:07:55,502 ERROR [notes-activity-service] de.notes.activity.rest.ActivityBaseResource  - Exception Occurred : Internal server error
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultDnsResolver.resolve(SystemDefaultDnsResolver.java:45)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:111)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamActivityRepository.getActivities(StreamActivityRepository.java:153)
        at io.getstream.client.apache.repo.StreamRepositoryImpl.getActivities(StreamRepositoryImpl.java:194)
        at io.getstream.client.service.FlatActivityServiceImpl.getActivities(FlatActivityServiceImpl.java:61)
        at de.notes.activity.rest.ActivityGetResource.getCarbookActivities(ActivityGetResource.java:101)
```

Comment: Something is going wrong with DNS resolution. What DNS servers and OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your hostname to just "api.getstream.io". While you *can* connect to our data centers directly on AWS using these IP addresses, the nature of our systems means that IP addresses may go stale, so you should really rely on DNS resolution to connect to Stream.